# GBM each time returns different results on the same sample.(R)

Tags: r, gbm

just little sample.

```
ames_train=structure(list(channel = c("aviasales", "aviasales", "aviasales", 
"aviasales", "aviasales", "g", "g", "aviasales", "aviasales", 
"aviasales", "g", "aviasales"), price_category = c("16_25", "5_10", 
"5_10", "0_5", "5_10", "0_5", "5_10", "10_16", "16_25", "10_16", 
"5_10", "10_16"), flight_type = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), offer_type_category = c(1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), flight_category = c(11L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 11L, 7L, 2L, 11L), client_platform = c("android", 
"macos", "windows", "windows", "android", "iphone", "android", 
"iphone", "android", "macos", "android", "android"), client_type = c("mobile", 
"desktop", "desktop", "desktop", "mobile", "mobile", "mobile", 
"mobile", "mobile", "desktop", "mobile", "mobile"), flight_area = c("RU", 
"RU", "RU", "RU", "RU", "RU", "RU", "RU", "RU", "RU", "RU", "RU"
), product_kit_id = c(31L, 54L, 41L, 54L, 41L, 44L, 41L, 42L, 
23L, 44L, 41L, 31L), Y = c(45L, 23L, 366L, 0L, 0L, 
899L, 0L, 433L, 0L, 0L, 35L, 699L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

build simple gbm model

```
# for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# train GBM model
gbm.fit.final109 <- gbm(
  formula = Y ~ .,
  distribution = "gaussian",
  data = ames_train,
  n.trees = 483,
  interaction.depth = 5,
  shrinkage = 0.1,
  n.minobsinnode = 5,
  bag.fraction = .65, 
  train.fraction = 1,
  n.cores = NULL, # will use all cores by default
  verbose = FALSE
)
```

predict the results

```
pred <- predict(gbm.fit.final109, n.trees = gbm.fit.final109$n.trees, ames_test)
pred=as.data.frame(pred)
str(pred)
```

the result
567,864,900...

Ок, run this code on this data
and the new result
356,123,231...
Why it so? and How fix, that on the same data was same results?
Thank you

Comment: with your example data and code I recive this error message: `Error in gbm.fit(x = x, y = y, offset = offset, distribution = distribution,  : 
  The data set is too small or the subsampling rate is too large: `nTrain * bag.fraction <= n.minobsinnode``

Comment: did you set the seed again?

Comment: Please include all the non-base R libraries that you are using. Which package does `gbm` function come from?

Comment: @RonakShah library(gbm)